# Problem in parsing between different software

Tags: java

In my Mac I don't have a problem in IntelliJ but in my University's PC it gives me an error of Unparsable date. I can't manage to understand the problem.

```
public static List<BusPosition> readBusPositions() throws ParseException {
            String wholeText = Utils.readFile("busPositionsNew.txt");
            List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(wholeText.split("\\\n"));
            List<BusPosition> busPositions = new ArrayList<>();
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSSa");
            for (String line : lines) {
                String[] split = line.split(",");
                double latitude = new BigDecimal(split[3]).doubleValue();
                double longitude = new BigDecimal(split[4]).doubleValue();
                Date timestamp = format.parse(split[5]);
                busPositions.add(new BusPosition(split[0], split[1], split[2], latitude, longitude, timestamp));
            }
            return busPositions;
        }
```

Comment: what is the exact error?

Comment: At a guess, there is a difference in locale. Try setting an explicit locale on the `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mar  4 2019 10:38:56:000AM"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)

Comment: Difference on line endings between Windows and Mac? You split on \n, perhaps there is still a \r at the end of your date part?

Comment: By the way, you are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: Tell us the exact error, and the exact exception. Edit your Question to provide this further detail. Voting to close until then.